# update changed column in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables in Oracle
like

table 1:

| id | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three | Four |

table 2:

| id | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three | Four |

they have the same rows and data.

I want to write a procedure that
when I run, each row that change in table 1 update in table 2 and the main point is:
only columns that change update. because different columns may be change in a row each time.
I do not want to update whole columns in a row.

Comment: What's the point in having two tables which are exactly the same?

Comment: I need that in real project. I just make the problem easy.

Comment: Are you trying to mirror changes as they happen (i.e. may need a trigger on table 1 that updates related data on table 2), or as a clean-up some time after table 1 was updated? I understand only touching *rows* that have changed, but why do you specifically only want to touch *columns* that have changed? Updating a column to its current value shouldn't matter. Or are changes being made to table 2 independently and you don't want to overwrite those unless the same column is then changed in table 1? You may have lost vital information, or at least added confusion, by simplifying too much... *8-)

Comment: `create materialized view table2 on prebuilt table refresh on commit fast with rowid as select * from table1` But you need a MV log on `table1` also

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a non-bogus requirement :) the only way to track a change to a column is with a trigger.

```
create or replace trigger t1_upd before update on t1 for each row is
begin

    if :old.c1 != :new.c1 then

         update t2
         set t2.c1 = :new.c1
         where t2.id = :new.id;

    end if;

    if :old.c2 != :new.c2 then

         update t2
         set t2.c2 = :new.c2
         where t2.id = :new.id;

    end if;

    -- and so on

end;
/
```

Untested code, may contain errors.

Notes

1. If you have lots of columns this could be an expensive process: you're turning a single update into multiple updates
2. It presumes the pre-existence of matching rows in the second table. You will need to handle that if you don't already (say with an insert trigger).